# Add Trello Card results in "Error - Malformed URL:"

Tags: ruby, api, trello

I'm using ruby-trello gem for creating cards in a Trello list.
For my testing credentials this works fine, for the credentials I use on a production setup I get "Trello::Error - Malformed URL:"

The "Malformed URL" is a direct response from Trello, and I can't get my head around why, and how to fix this.

There is little to no documentation on API response errors by Trello.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should watch what you application is sending to Trello.

You should also aread the [API that Trello offers](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference) and search for the specific request and its response. Also you can probe if the Keys are correct in Trello's Sandbox.

As last option write an issue on [Github's gem](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello/issues) or ask for assistance to Trello.

Hope it helps.